Asset validation failed - Invalid signature (Code object is not signed at all)
I have my app waiting to be uploaded to the App Store.. So I went to the Xcode and then to the product and archive. All goes good but while uploading, I am getting error as shown in the image 
I did try creating new certificates (DEV,Distribution) and all but none of these worked.
